# CSRF token missing or incorrect. Django 1.8 restaurant app

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error (on Chrome):

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect
```

What I am trying to do is make a restaurant application. I have my menu items and am trying to create a record in my orders table. Any time one button is clicked I want to add that entry into the orders table

Here are my files:

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from app.models import *

def menu(request):
    menus = Menu.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('app/menu.html', {'menus':menus})

def menudetails(request,id):
    menu = Menu.objects.get(pk = id)
    return render_to_response('app/menudetails.html', {'menu':menu})

def myorders(request,id):
   # if request.method == "POST":
        #order = Order.createorder(Menu(pk=id))
       # order.save()
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = OrderForm()
        return render(request, 'app/menudetails.html',{ 'form':form })
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/menu');


def addmenu(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = MenuForm()
        return render(request, 'app/addmenu.html',{ 'form':form })
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = MenuForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/menu');

def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )

def contact(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/contact.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Contact',
            'message':'Your contact page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )

def about(request):
    """Renders the about page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/about.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'About',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )
```

`urls.py`

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from app.forms import BootstrapAuthenticationForm

# Uncomment the next lines to enable the admin:
# from django.conf.urls import include
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #url(r'^myorders$', 'app.views.myorders', name = 'myorders'),
    url(r'^menu$', 'app.views.menu', name = 'menu'),
    url(r'^addmenu$', 'app.views.addmenu', name = 'addmenu'),
    url(r'^menu/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'app.views.menudetails', name = 'menudetails'),
    url(r'^menu/(?P<id>\d+)/order$', 'app.views.myorders', name = 'myorders'),
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^contact$', 'app.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', 'app.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^login/$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/login.html',
            'authentication_form': BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title':'Log in',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            }
        },
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
        {
            'next_page': '/',
        },
        name='logout'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from datetime import datetime

class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Menu Item", max_length = 50)
    desc = models.CharField("Description", max_length = 100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places = 2)

class MenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu;
        fields = ['name','desc','price'];

class Order(models.Model):
    menuItem = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
    ordercreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    orderupdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    user = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank = True)

    def createorder(cls, menu):
        order = cls(menuItem = menu)
        return order
```

Comment: In your templates, inside the form tags, you need to have the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to avoid this error, solutions as below:

1. Add `{% csrf_token %}` in your template

Link:[csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

2. Add `@csrf_exempt` on your view

Link:[csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)

Comment: I added the \@csrf_exempt and got a \@csrf_exempt not defined error in views.py. I already had the {% csrf_token %} in my form template

Comment: <div class="container">
        <h2>{{ menu.name }}</h2>
        <h3> Description:</h3> <p>{{ menu.desc }}</p>

        <form action="/menu/{{ menu.id }}/order" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Order now</button>
        </form>

        
    </div>

Comment: Nope. Still messing around with it

Comment: @JaySachdeva ,is your problem okay?

Comment: Yea, I was able to get it with csrf_exempt, thank you!

Comment: @JaySachdeva ,would you select my answer to best answer?

Comment: I dont know where to do that

Comment: The vote number and check sign locate on the left of answer. You just click the check sign it means it's the best answer for you.